# How do I change the color of all images on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site where I want to have images that change from black and white to colour when the viewer scrolls. The images are originally in color but I used a css filter to create the grayscale effect.

How can I achieve this effect on the scroll? I know how to create the effect when the viewer hovers over the image but I want to make it so that it changes on scroll.

Here is my code for the hover effect:

```
.contact {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
}

.contact:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(0);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you looked into something like scrollspy?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not code writing service, we can only help you with the code you've written.

Comment: You need use jquery and execute the scroll() event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class for black & white and another for color :

```
.contact {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);*
}
.contact:hover, .contact-color {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(0);
}
```

Then add a listener on window :

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('contact');
var changeFrom = 500; // from which amount of scroll do you want the effect to appear ?

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= changeFrom ) {
    [].forEach.call(images, function(image) {
      image.classList.add('contact-color');
    });
  }
  else {
    [].forEach.call(images, function(image) {
      image.classList.remove('contact-color');
    });
  }
});
```

Color will will change when the the defined amount of vertical scrolling is reached and will revert if you scroll up. I don't know if it's exactly what you want but you may easily adapt it depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver! This worked great and it was easier than I thought! Thank you again for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but I assumed that you wanted your images to turn b/w while scrolling. Independent on where you are on the page.

Javascript has a onScroll event, but that fires every time a scroll occurs, so the first time you get this event, change to b/w and change the color back if a scroll event hasn't been fired in half a second. I used setTimeout() to do this with a delay.

Heres a fiddle that shows the concept: https://jsfiddle.net/rzqcwzrh/107/

```
$("#idOfUl").on( 'scroll', function(){
  if(!$( "#idOfUl" ).hasClass( "red" ))
    $("#idOfUl").addClass("red");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#idOfUl").removeClass("red");
  }, 500);
});
```